# int to byte, "cannot be resolved to a variable". What is wrong?

Tags: java, int, byte

what is wrong with this;

```
public class cast {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        double x, y; 
        int i;
        char c; 

        x = 10.0; 
        y = 3.0; 

        i = (int) (x / y); 
        System.out.println("Integer outcome of x / y = " + i); 

        i = 100; //Assaigning new value to i. 

        b = (byte) i;  
        System.out.println("The value of i is: " + b); 

    }

}
```

It gives me the following error message; 
b cannot be resolved to a variable.

Although I did exactly as they did in the book ( I think, re read the book instruction like five times....)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*b* is not a declared variable in your example. Before you can use a variable you have to declare it. If you don't do this Java does not know what *b* stands for and doesn't know what to do with it.  Try

```
byte b = (byte) i;
```

instead. Alternatively you can also add the line

```
byte b;
```

to the beginning of your program. This tells Java that you want *b* to be a variable that can hold a byte.